# Find the bad links

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a list of about 6k links. I need to go through each one and see if the page it leads to contains particular words.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: are u a spammer trying the get email addresses? :-)

Comment: Haha no, I have to find the spammy links! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirty solution:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read link ; do
    wget -qO- "$link" | grep -qiFf words.lst - && echo "$link"
done < links.lst > found.lst
```

Links should be kept in `links.lst`, one link per line. Words should be kept in `words.lst`, one word per line.

Comment: OK it's running now, and doing well! Let's see how it goes!

Comment: +1, but no need for bash.  Could just as well be `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I created one for you:

Create a file called words.txt containing the words to check separed by spaces.

Create a file called links.url containing a list of url to check one per line

Create a file called crawler.sh containing the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A file with a list of urls one per line
LINKS_FILE="links.url"
# A file with a list of words separed by spaces
WORDS_FILE="words.txt"

HTTP_CLIENT="/usr/bin/wget -O - "

rm -f /tmp/temp.html
for link in `cat "$LINKS_FILE"`
do
        # Downloading page
        echo "--"
        echo "Scanning link: $link"
        $HTTP_CLIENT "$link" > /tmp/temp.html
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
                echo "## Problem downloading resource $link" 1>&2
                continue
        fi

        # Checking words
        for word in `cat "$WORDS_FILE"`
        do
                echo "Checking for the word \"$word\"..."
                if [ "x`grep -i $word /tmp/temp.html`" != "x" ]
                then
                        echo "** The word $word is found into the uri \"$link\""
                        continue 2
                fi
        done
        echo "** No words found into \"$link\""
        echo "--"
        echo
done
rm -f /tmp/temp.html
```

Run the wrapper.

Comment: Don't use `for` to iterate over `cat`: `while read -r link; do ... done < "$LINKS_FILE"`. `if [ "x..." != "x" ]` is archaic and you can test `grep` directly: if grep -qsi "$word" /tmp/temp.html` (options may vary depending on `grep` version). You should use `mktemp` or `tempfile` to make temporary files. Nested loops are going to be slower than the accepted answer's `grep -f`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Thank you for your suggestions. I try to write portable shellscripts, it will probably run on many unices without modifications. Anyway thank you!

Comment: There's nothing especially non-portable in what I proposed. You can easily make the `if grep` more portable: `if grep -i "$word" filename > /dev/null >&2`. And you can do existence checks for `mktemp` and `tempfile` with a fallback to a fixed name. The `x` technique is only necessary for truly *ancient* Bourne shells.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a selenium script to visit each url and then check that those words appear on those pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest way, but came up first:

```
#!bin/bash

while read url
do
    content=$(wget $url -q -O -)

    # and here you can check
    # if there are matches in $content

done < "links.txt"
```